# Какой тип данных лучше всего подходит для хранения очков в Redis?

Tags: node-redis, redis

Есть две кнопки на веб-странице: `like` и`unlike`.
Когда пользователь нажимает на эти кнопки, посылается запрос, подсчитывающий количество кликов.

Что является лучшим и удобным из типов в редисе, чтобы сохранить подсчет?

У меня есть несколько вариантов:

- Использование `key`.
  - Использовать `hash` со счетом одного поля и ключ кнопки ID.
  - Использовать `sortet sets`.

Проблема в том, что нужно показать имена пользователей, которые кнопки и количество кликов каждой кнопки.

Если делать так, для каждой записи будет создаваться отдельный `set`, что не удобно:

```
$key = 'reposts:news:200';
$time = time();
$this->redis->zadd($key, $time, array());
```

Comment: А зачем set? Нельзя просто использовать в виде ключа ID кнопки и значение - кол-во кликов?

Comment: Это для какого типа? А где хранить id пользователя?

Comment: Прошу прощения, упустил это из вида - невнимательно прочитал задание. Для каждой кнопки создавать set. В set  сохранять объект JSON с необходимыми данными о пользователе и клике, каждый раз, когда происходит этот самый клик. Нужно только помнить, что количество записей в set ограничено.

Comment: А какие ограничения? Дело в том, что в системе 10 типов информации. Если будет 1 млн записей - то нужно создавать 1 млн `set`. К тому же это должен быть sorted set? Что будет в качестве ключа значения и score?

Comment: Я проверил в документации, вроде ограничений нет для set. Я перепутал с Hashes. А зачем sorted set? Зачем создавать 1 млн. sets? Вы написали, что всего две кнопки. Для каждой кнопки создается свой set. В set каждой кнопки записываете JSON объект со всеми необходимыми данными.

Comment: Например, есть статья - для нее 2 кнопки. Есть другая статья - для нее тоже 2 кнопки. В системе также могут быть новости видео и т.д.

Comment: Ничего не поделаешь. Прийдется создавать для каждой кнопки свой set. На производительность Redis это никак не повлияет. Важно, что работать с данными будет в последствии удобно и не нужно будет делать сложных поисков внутри Redis.

Comment: Тогда что будет выступать в качестве значения и score? Если в качестве scope будет id пользователя, кто нажал кнопку, а в качестве значения - кол-во сделанных лаков, тогда каждый раз будет перезаписываться значение, так как одинакового score не может быть. Нужен какой-то счетчик, который бы хранил все id пользователей, кто нажал кнопку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать SET.

В качестве ключа делать button_id, а в список добавлять JSON объект с данными о пользователе. Таким образом записи в Redis будут иметь следующий вид

```
button1:
    {"user_id":"1", "name":"Pupkin"}
    {"user_id":"101", "name":"Vaskin"}
    ....
    {"user_id":"11", "name":"Puper"}
```

Узнать кол-во нажатий можно легко узнать подсчитав кол-во элементов в set.